# Adding Extra Fields to Rails Model to Reduce Unnecessary DB Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

We have a model, Booking, that is connected to numerous other models.

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :business
  belongs_to :employee

  # a whole lot more below

end
```

In the show view there is a line of code:

```
Room Service Employee: #{booking.employee.first_name}
```

Because of this line, there's a DB query looking up the first name of the booking's designated employee.

When 10,000 bookings are viewed each day, that's 10,000 DB calls for a stupid first name.

My question is, does it make sense to add a "employee_name" field to the Booking model and write the employee's name there instead of going to the DB for that information each time? It might only take 25ms for the DB query, but they add up. Does it really make a difference?

I'm the lone programmer at my company so I don't have any seniors devs to ask. I've Googled, but can't find anything useful. Preach to me internet!

Thanks for your opinions!

Comment: Yes it's extra queries but isn't it premature to optimize such a thing? If you duplicate the name into both tables you will have to maintain it whenever the name change. Its a bit more complexity - is it worth it? Maybe if you're really hunting for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally avoid duplication unless its a last resort.

You can prevent the additional query by using `.eager_load` if you know that you want to use it upfront:

```
@booking = Booking.eager_load(:employee)
                  .find(params[:id])
```

This loads both the booking and employee in a single database query. If you're display and list of bookings and the related employees you can use `.includes` to avoid a [N+1 query](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations):

```
@bookings = Booking.includes(:employee)
                   .all

@bookings.each { |b| puts b.employee.first_name } # will only do a single query
```

This will "lazy load" all the employee records at once when you first call `booking.employee` (on an instance of the collection).

If you don't want to load the entire employee record you can just join and select the desired column(s) off that table:

```
@bookings = Booking.joins(:employee)
                   .select(
                     Booking.arel_table[Arel.star],
                     Employee.arel_table[:first_name].as("employee_name")
                   )

@bookings.each { |b| puts b.employee_name }
```

Any columns that you select and assign an alias will be available as a method in the models in the result set. Magic!

See:

- [Making sense of ActiveRecord joins, includes, preload, and eager_load](https://scoutapm.com/blog/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where)